# javax.jcr.ItemExistsException when moving node in JCR

Tags: aem, jcr

I am trying to move the nodes from one path to another & getting the exception :

```
com.aem.tagmodels.MoveNodes Source is --> /content/dam/geometrixx/portraits/scott_reynolds.jpg
10.12.2014 16:38:27.952 *INFO* [127.0.0.1 [1418209707948] GET /content/AEMProject/Test/jcr:content/par/session_op.html HTTP/1.1] com.aem.tagmodels.MoveNodes Destination is --> /content/dam/geometrixx/drm
10.12.2014 16:38:27.952 *INFO* [127.0.0.1 [1418209707948] GET /content/AEMProject/Test/jcr:content/par/session_op.html HTTP/1.1] com.aem.tagmodels.MoveNodes Session --> session-38784
10.12.2014 16:38:27.952 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1418209707948] GET /content/AEMProject/Test/jcr:content/par/session_op.html HTTP/1.1] com.aem.tagmodels.MoveNodes Error is javax.jcr.ItemExistsException: /content/dam/geometrixx/drm
```

I have checked there is no node inside drm with the same name as scott_reynolds.jpg . Below is my code snippet.

```
session.getWorkspace().move(source,destination);
        session.save();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use parent node, `/content/dam/geometrixx/drm`, as a destination. This destination exists and that's why you are getting the exception, as the `move()` method expects the complete new path as the second parameter:

> Strictly speaking, the destAbsPath parameter is actually an absolute path to the parent node of the new location, appended with the new name desired for the moved node.

(from [Javadoc](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Workspace.html#move(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))).

You should use full path, parent followed by the new name, for instance: `/content/dam/geometrixx/drm/scott_reynolds.jpg`.

Comment: K Thanks, Actually my requirement was input two nodetypes that already under / hierarchy and move the child node from one to another, Here problem is, destination path must be provided by author which exist in crx, in that case we have destination already & just want to move the nodes below it. Is any other method in API will be helpful.

Comment: If you have the parent destination node, simply append `/someName` to it.